# Sql performance on dedicated machine vs webserver

Tags: sql-server

In terms of performance, not security, which is the better option:

same cpu's

1:  1 Webserver with MS Sql with XRAM

2:  1 Webserver with .5XRAM  AND 1 dedicated SQL machine with .5XRAM

Comment: You'd get more pointed and objective responses on serverfault.com. A [rough] rule of thumb is SQL makes the best use of the RAM, and should therefore be favored in this regards.  Since unfortunatly solution #2 split the RAM in half(!), #1 may be preferable in many cases, even considering the loss of extra CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on your use case, and the only way to determine that is with testing.

If (as seems likely given the form of your question) you're using a virtualization solution, like XEN machines or something similar, you're better of going with all on a single machine.

The reason for this is that, given a bigger "slice" of the physical hardware, you almost always get higher CPU priority for all processes running in that machine in most VPS setups. If someone else on the same server is loading it pretty hard, you will get proportionally more clock cycles for either of your tasks, particularly in the case where one process is using less CPU than the other.

Answer (score 2):

Use two machines would be my recommendation, more room to grow, easier to configure, and you won't have issues with conflicting 'best practices'. See this discussion here: [When can I host IIS and SQL Server on the same machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401834/when-can-i-host-iis-and-sql-server-on-the-same-machine/1429038#1429038)

Answer (score 0):

I Assume that you are trying to run 1 or 2 VPC's on the same machine?

In both cases you have too little RAM to run anything other than functional testing.

I would go for number 1, we use that when testing systems with VPC's.